# Refreshing Catalog window from ArcMap using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, catalog-window

I am running my script from ArcMap and I have the Catalog window open on the side. I delete some extra files in the end of my script but I have to **[refresh the Catalog window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004q000000)** to see them go. So I decided to use the following code to refresh it automatically:

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env
import os.path

# Parameters
XS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Environment Definition
desc = arcpy.Describe(XS)
path = desc.path
env.workspace = path #Everything is saved at *path*

arcpy.RefreshCatalog(path)
```

But it doesn't work either. Any idea what is missing here?

I am running my script though a toolbox.
And my files are located at *path*.

Comment: How is the script being executed? In the python window or through a script or tool?  Is the path to a file or folder?

Comment: @Barbarossa: I revised my post accordingly.

Comment: I've just experimented with the command.  arcpy.RefreshCatalog(path) seems to work on folders and geodatabases from the python window in ArcMap.  It also works on geodatabases from a script tool, but not on folders.  Is this what you have experienced as well?

Comment: @Barbarossa: I have not tried it on geodatabases yet, but yes, I am trying to refresh the contents of a folder rather than a geodatabase.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Can you reproduce the issue using the Sample Code from the [**RefreshCatalog**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004q000000) documentation?  If so, it would be good to edit that or an alternative test case into your question.

Comment: @PolyGeo: I am using ArcGIS 10.0, and a simplified form of my script is added to the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop on Windows 7 SP1 (64 bit) and the code below, which I just pasted into the Python window of ArcMap:

```
import shutil
import arcpy

input_folder = "c:/temp/testFolder"
target_folder = "c:/temp/testFolder_backup"
input_gdb = "c:/temp/test.gdb"
target_gdb = "c:/temp/test_backup.gdb"

# Copy a directory tree to a backup location
shutil.copytree(input_folder, target_folder)
shutil.copytree(input_gdb, target_gdb)

# Refresh the Catalog window for the new directory
arcpy.RefreshCatalog(target_folder)
arcpy.RefreshCatalog(target_gdb)
```

The Catalog window simply did not refresh to show the new folder or file geodatabase.

I also tried to refresh the folder above using:

```
arcpy.RefreshCatalog("C:/temp")
```

but this too had no effect.

As soon as I right-clicked on C:\temp and chose Refresh to do it manually both the new folder and file geodatabase appeared.

I recommend that you report to your local Esri support that you are experiencing what appears to be [bug NIM077922](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc3OTIy).